# Prevent form submit with jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using [Inline Form Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) to validate a form. Now I want to prevent the form submit. I tried something like this :

```
$("#ws-form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$("#quotation-form").submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Preventing form submit works for **#ws-form** but not for **#quotation-form**

These forms have almost the same validation:

```
$("#ws-form").validationEngine('attach',{
    onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
        if(status === true){
            // some treatment
        }
    }
});
```

You can find an example of the forms [here](http://www.courtier-en-mutuelle.com/demo_ws/). My question how can I prevent the submit for this form?

Comment: Why exactly would you need to stop a submit of a valid form? Surely you should modify your validation?

Comment: I need to prevent the submit because I make an ajax query when the form is valid

Comment: Can you add a tag <form onSubmit="return false;"></form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inline validation is not required then you can do the following.

First add a jquery.validate.js file in your header. 
Then modify the click behavior of the button as follows:

```
$("#submitButton").live("click",function(){
$("#frm").validate();
if($("#frm").valid())
{
   // ajax call
}
return false;// if required to be on same page.
});
```

Comment: Inline validation is compulsory for this form :(

Answer (score 0):

```
"ajaxUserCall": {
    "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
    "extraData": "name=eric",
    "extraDataDynamic": ['#user_id', '#user_email'],
    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
    "alertTextOk": "All good!",
    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
},
```